# Android ListViews Force Selection

Tags: android, listview

I'm inexperienced with Android and working on an app that simply displays a school bell schedule in the form of a table and hopefully highlight/apply a background color to a ListView item representative of the current period.

Currently I have attempted to do so via setting a listSelector color:

**From activity_bell_schedule.xml:**

```
<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/lstPeriods"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:listSelector="@color/colorAccent"
        android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

However, I then need to be able to lock/force the selection to remain as the ListView item of the current period. I tried by setting it in a function called through the onCreate function of my BellScheduleActivity class and this(I used 2 for the position for testing purposes):

**From BellScheduleActivity.java:**

```
lvp.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println(position);
            lvp.setSelection(2);
            lvp.setItemChecked(2, true);
            lvt.setSelection(2);
        }
    });
```

I have tried a variety of methods involving selection highlighting and selecting. If anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong or has another approach that might work, I would really appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting a custom adapter to your listview. In that adapter you can define custom behavior.

In your case it would be to override the following methods in the adapter-

- getItemViewType()
- getViewTypeCount()
- getView()

In that adapter you can define your two view types. And in getView() you can call getItemViewType() and define custom behavior.

[Example for getItemViewType() is here](http://learnncode.co/android/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/)

[Another example which is similar to your question](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView)

This should solve your issue. Let me know if it works. This is like the default pattern in displaying custom listViews.

P.S. I would recommend you use RecyclerView as it is the newer(and better)ListView and is the new standard in Material Design.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed. I had two list views before, now I just have one thanks to using this with a custom adapter. I'm currently looking into the RecyclerView for the future.